# How to define relationship between two columns of which one is primary key?

Tags: database-design

For a project, I'm creating a database model, and I'm not completely sure if I'm on the right path. I've tried to find the answer, but came up empty.

I have two tables. One of them is a 'subclass' of the other.

Example: `Animal` and `Horse`. `Horse` has a primary key called `HorseId`, and `Animal` has a primary key called `AnimalId`. `HorseId` is a foreign key referencing `AnimalId`. So far so good.

Now I want to add a column `Type` to the `Animal` table, so I know which animal it is. `Animal` now has `AnimalId` and `Type` as a column.

**Table Animal**

```
AnimalId (PK)  
Type
```

**Table Horse**

```
HorseId (PK, FK ref Animal.AnimalId)
```

However, the `AnimalId` which identifies a horse should always have 'Horse' as a `Type`. A possibility would be to make `Type` a part of the primary key, but that doesn't seem right, as `AnimalId` uniquely identifies a row on its one.

Another option would be to create an alternate key containing the two columns. However, my validator tells me 'primary key is a subset of alternate key' (which is correct), and warns me about it. Is it not allowed?

How should I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to create a rule that force Type to be Horse if the AnimalID is present in the Horse table?

Comment: That would be solving everything if that is possible.
What I'm saying in my first post is only solving part of the problem. It ensures that an AnimalId can only have one Type. What you would really want, is to ensure that the Type is the same as the table the Id is present in.
However, I'm not sure if you want to make constraints like that on database level. If I can do the first part, I would be quite happy as well.

Comment: on solution would be a trigger that, when you insert a record in `Animal` with `Type = Horse`, insert a new row in `Horse`. Which database are you using?

Comment: I think it would be the other way around, when creating a new record for Horse (which will have more columns), it will add a row to the Animal table with Type = Horse.
You can do this automatically? That would solve the problem, if you can also restrain anyone from directly inserting a row into Animal. Is that possible?
I'm using SQuirrel SQL database.

Comment: I'm not really sure if it works (because `AnimalID` is a FK for `Horse`), but maybe you can try with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the `Horse` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a trigger solved multiple problems.
I had to change the foreign key relationship, because it was defined the wrong way. `AnimalId` should reference `HorseId` if I want to be able to create a new record in `Horse`.
Furthermore, an alternate key is not necessary. The primary key and foreign key already ensure that a record within `Animal` references one record in `Horse`, so there will always be one `Type`.
To ensure that the `Type` in `Animal` is correct, I have been able to create a trigger. The trigger automatically inserts a record into `Animal` with the correct `Type` and `Id` after a record in `Horse` has been inserted.
The trigger and the primary key of `Animal` ensure that no one can enter a row into `Animal` directly and inserting a wrong `Type`.

Trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE trigger Trigger  
ON Horse  
AFTER INSERT  
AS  
DECLARE @Id uniqueidentifier  
SET @Id = (SELECT HorseId FROM inserted)  
INSERT Animal VALUES (@Id, 'Horse')
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!